# Grabbing data from a list in a for loop in C#

Tags: c#, html, css, list

I am trying to cycle through a list and create a new table for each site in my list

My controller looks like this

```
 List<string> OffReportColumns = new List<string>(7);     
 List<List<string>> OffReportRows = new List<List<string>>();   
            foreach (Site s in sites)
            {                           
                OffReportColumns.Add(s.Name);
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost");
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost With Labour");

   OffReportRows.Add(new List<string>
                {
                    "Parts",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                });
            }
```

And my View looks like this

```
@foreach (Site s in sites)
        {
            <tr style="color:black">
                @foreach (var col in ViewBag.OffReportColumns)
                {
                    <th>@col </th>
                }            
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:black">
                   @foreach (var cell in ViewBag.OffReportRows)
                   {
                       <td>@cell</td>
                   }
            </tr>
        }
```

Currently this makes the page look like 
[image: Page]

But I instead want it to be layed out so it looks like this

`"Eric Car Stock "             "Average Cost"     "Average Cost with Labour"`

`"In-House Use "               "Average Cost"     "Average Cost with Labour"`

`"Havey Kuhar's Car Stock "    "Average Cost"     "Average Cost with Labour"`

Each table will have data underneath it that corresponds to their site

How can I change my code to accomplish this?

**What I tried**

In my view I had first tried having my code do this

```
//Removed for foreach (Site s in sites)

   @foreach (var row in ViewBag.OffReportRows)

             <tr style="color:black">
                    @foreach (var cell in ViewBag.OffReportRows)
                    {
                        <td>@cell</td>
                    }
             </tr>
            }
```

But this would only expand on the lists instead of creating new lists

Comment: There's a few ways, show us what you actually tried and what isn't working so we can better assist you.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I have added another example of something I tried but most of the time it's just been tweaking the code a little bit and trying some little changes

Comment: are those two columns are static data "Average Cost"     "Average Cost with Labour" ?

Comment: @HasanElsherbiny Yeah it's static but my page will include more data that what is shown. I just cut it down for simplicity and to get an idea of how to go about doing the rest of my tables as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code snippet, all columns for all sites are added to one list. 2 dimensions are becoming 1 dimension. Without the loop, it is effectively written as

```
OffReportColumns.Add("Eric Car Stock ");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost With Labour");

OffReportColumns.Add("In-House Use ");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost With Labour");

OffReportColumns.Add("Havey Kuhar's Car Stock ");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("");
OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost With Labour");
```

The second code snippet says, "For each site, of which there are 3, create a table row. In each row, for each OffReportColumns, of which there are 21, create a table column with text from the inner loop.

This is why all columns from all sites are appearing on each of the 3 rows.

A better approach would be to not have the `OffReportColumns` list at all. Instead, the view can be written like this

```
@foreach (Site s in sites)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@s.Name</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Average Cost</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Average Cost With Labour</td>
    </tr>
}
```

This creates a row of 7 columns for each site. The first column of each row will be the name of the site.

Answer (score 1):

as you stated in your comment there are two columns are static data and the only dynamic data is the site can simply loop throw the sites and display them as following

```
    @foreach (Site s in sites)
    {
        <tr style="color:black">
        <td>@Site</td>
        <td>Average Cost</td>
        <td>Average Cost with Labour</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

you can also remove adding columns to list and viewbag in your controller since they are not necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately I simplified my code down to much. I have added more to it. Because under each column there will be another data list that will correspond with the proper site. Thats why I had it setup the way that I currently do

Comment: @chris so you have to edit your question to clarify it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement several things first I would try to modify the column size `col-xs-3`
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

If this doesn't work try to collapse two join in 1 `colspan = "2"` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

finally I would try the class = `"vw-100"` 
property https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/sizing/

I let you a simple example so you can implement it open it in **full window to see it correctly**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div  style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  <br>
    <div style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  <br>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```